# Understanding Slim framework basics

Tags: php, rest, slim, web-frameworks

I recently used the **Slim** framework to create an API. I want to have things clear to me.

1. What exactly is the `Slim` object?
2. What exactly makes `$app->run()` call the routing or the methods?
3. Is the RESTful interface itself handled by the `Slim()` object $app?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The creator of the Slim Framework (Josh Lockhart) has a blog on the subject where he briefly explains some of the points you mention:

[Calendar with slim](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/jquery-calendar-with-ajax-api)

I personally learn by doing. There's a channel called, phpacademy on youtube where Alex and Co. have some great tutorials.

[Blog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRfYgco3xo4)

[Authentication system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXKCNgfdAAM)